# Access denied with code 403 (Parallel Plesk)

Tags: php, mysql, plesk, http-status-code-403

I've made a website working fine on localhost with wamp. I've put it online on my client's hosting solution.
It's in Php with a very simple MySql database.

The problem comes when I try to update or create some "events" from the admin interface I've created (a simple SQL update or create command) : "Forbidden You do not have permission to access this document.
Web Server at guymarin.com"
And the whole server seems to be stuck for about 20 minutes each time!

**The error log says** :

```
[Wed Jul 02 06:24:38 2014] [error] [client 70.81.162.225] 
ModSecurity: [file "/etc/httpd/modsecurity.d/10_asl_rules.conf"] [line "1018"] [id `"350147"] [rev "147"] [msg "Atomicorp.com WAF Rules: Potentially Untrusted Web Content 

Detected"] [data "336"] [severity "CRITICAL"] Access denied with code 403 (phase 2).` 
`Match of "rx ((?:submit(?:\\\\+| )?(request)?(?:\\\\+| )?>+|<<(?:\\\\+| )remove|(?:sign ?in|log ?(?:in|out)|next|modifier|envoyer|add|continue|wei ter|account|results|select)(?:\\\\+| )?>+)$|^< ?\\\\??(?: |\\\\+)?xml|^<samlp|^>> ?$)" against "REQUEST_URI" required. [hostname "www.guymarin.com"] [uri "/admin/create_even.php"] [unique_id` "U7Pr9risJLQAAGsYcfUAAAAO"]
```

What do you think I should do in this case?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have activated WAF (mod_security) from Plesk security core. You can disable it or switch to non-blocking mode.